# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Tags: jquery, drupal

I'm using colour box on a project and this error in IE is causing the rest of the script to brake thanks to a uncaught type error for .split on line 11 any clues would be great

```
Drupal.behaviors.PROJECT = {

attach: function (context, settings) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $(".inlinepop").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", href:"#login-pop"});

  //Solve problem with Youtube videos overflow
  params = '?wmode=transparent&rel=0';
  url = $('#content').find('iframe').attr('src');
  url = url.split('?');
  url = url[0] + params;
  $('#content').find('iframe').attr('src', url);

  //Set max width of video according to div
  width_container = $('#content').find('.node-content').width();
  $('#content').find('iframe').attr('width', width_container);
 });
 }
};
```

Comment: that's weird. One thing you should definitely do differently though is put `var` before your variable declarations. They way you're doing this now is setting them all as "Global Variables"

Comment: the next thing I would suggest would be running those lines one-at-a-time in the IE JavaScript console. Start with what `$('#content').find('iframe').attr('src');` gives you. (though you may have to do `$=jQuery` 1st).

Comment: You could otherwise improve this question be removing the Drupal stuff. Drupal (or server side stuff) is not the cause of your X-Browser problems. Show us the JavaScript as it is output to the Browser, and remove the Drupal tag.

Comment: Should be more clear this bug happens on all browsers but in IE its causing the rest of the script to break. the drupal.behaviours is browser side as it forms part for the drupal JavaScript api - http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/drupal-behaviors-quick-how

I'm not too keen changing the global declaration as another part of the system may be using them.

Comment: OH, I learned something about Drupal today!

Comment: And really (globals)? I can see maybe using `width_container` globally, but having url and params as globals seems like it may cause problems. At least rename these to be more specific. `youtube_url`, `youtube_zindex_fix_params`

Comment: The only way this can possibly happen is if the iframe you are targeting either doesn't exist, isn't in the content div, or doesn't have a src attribute. Test all three of those things.

Comment: I set up a fiddle (and invalidated my answer below, deleting now): http://jsfiddle.net/FNZXf/ It is NOT that there are multiple `iframe`s. That might be *another* bug, but not this one.

Comment: Good music choice! and the answer you deleted worked at squashing the error

http://jsfiddle.net/FNZXf/2/

Comment: @JamesKirkby ok hahh, weird, a mystery then

Answer (score 0):

I bet your problem is that you have more than one youtube video on the page.

The `find()` method below (line 11 perhaps) will return a set of all `iframe`s, not just one.

```
url = $('#content').find('iframe').attr('src');
```

You probably want to iterate over all of these:

```
$('#content iframe').each(function(){
  url = $(this).attr('src');
  url = url.split('?');
  url = url[0] + params;
})
```

**Edit:**

I turned `$('#content').find('iframe')` into `$('#content iframe')` in my example above. `find()` seems redundant. This should behave the same way

Comment: If it returns more than one, it will still work as long as the first one has a src attribute.

Comment: I believe you (but am going to test now). Was just guessing ;-)

Comment: i'm guessing the Uncaught TypeError: can also be produced if there wasn't any yt videos on the page as well as multiple which is more likely in this case to be the issue, the bug is squashed locally but i'll let you know when i try it on clients environment